# Select post that user has not seen before

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am looking for the most efficient way to create the following functionality. A user will load a page, which will give them a random post (from the user_post table), but must exclude posts that they have previously viewed. My data structure is (simplified):

```
user_post
---------
id (PK)


user_post_view
--------------
id (PK)
user_id
user_post_id
```

Where user_post is a stored post, and user_post_view is relates a user to a post that they have viewed. So, in English the query would be:

**Select a random post from the user_post table that there is no user_post_view record for**

I am using the Yii framework, but even a "normal" SQL statement will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM user_post p where 
your_user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_post_view WHERE user_post_id = p.id)
```

EDIT:

EXISTS actually probably makes more sense here...and I tacked on your LIMIT 1 in case you just wanted 1 post

```
SELECT * FROM user_post p where 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id FROM user_post_view WHERE user_post_id = p.id AND 
user_id = your_user_id) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.* FROM user_post p LEFT JOIN user_post_view pv ON (pv.user_id = your_user_id_here AND pv.user_post_id = p.id) WHERE pv.user_id = NULL
```

Should do the trick. It tries to LEFT JOIN with the user_post_view table. If this fails, all the fields from the right side of the join will be null. I'm taking this to my advantage.

Make sure, for efficiency, that you have an index that indexes user_id,user_post_id. Doesn't have to be primary, just an index of some sort to speed up requests.

Comment: thanks, creating an index for user_id is a good tip, appreciated